# Android - Firebase: Delete all child with specific id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

can somebody help me please i cant get it working.

The Database structure looks like:

```
-Abbos
     1509917361
         ELtRM6aTs9XYkMmdrDZ8gRxpgec2
             id: "ELtRM6aTs9XYkMmdrDZ8gRxpgec2"
             sortorder: -1509917361
         FLARM6aTs9XYkMmdrDZ8gRxpgeh4
             id: "FLARM6aTs9XYkMmdrDZ8gRxpgeh4"
             sortorder: -1509917361
     1509917780
         ELtRM6aTs9XYkMmdrDZ8gRxpgec2
             id: "ELtRM6aTs9XYkMmdrDZ8gRxpgec2"
             sortorder: -1509917780
```

Now i want to remove all entries with eg the id "ELtRM6aTs9XYkMmdrDZ8gRxpgec2"
but my code doesnt work.

```
Query queryRef = mUserAbosDB.child("Abbos").orderByChild("id").equalTo(current_user_id);

                queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use this-

```
    DatabaseReference drTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    drTest.child("Abbos").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(id)){
                    dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("TAG: ", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: i replaced id with current_user_id, but this code deletes all entries in Abbos. but i want only remove thoses with given id.

Comment: this block should stay:

     
         FLARM6aTs9XYkMmdrDZ8gRxpgeh4
             id: "FLARM6aTs9XYkMmdrDZ8gRxpgeh4"
             sortorder: -1509917361

Answer (score 0):

i got it :)

```
 DatabaseReference drTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                drTest.child("Abbos").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                               areaSnapshot.child(current_user_id).getRef().setValue(null);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Thank you Arif Khan